# Switching replication master in cascading replication scenario

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.3

Imagine I have 3 PostgreSQL 9.3 databases (A, B, and C) set up in a cascading, streaming replication scenario (i.e. am *NOT* manually shipping WAL files, am having Postgres ship them over TCP internally) like so:

```
A --> B
      |
      V
      C
```

where A is the replication master for B, and B is the replication master for C.

If B fails (goes offline but doesn't [failover](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/warm-standby-failover.html)) and I need to make C use A as replication master as quickly as possible, is it safe for me to skip [rebuilding](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) C from A and just set up A as C's replication master? I would do so by turning off the Postgres service on C, modifying the master host in the [replication.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/recovery-config.html) file on C to point to A, and then starting the Postgres service on C. I've done this in practice and C replicates off of A without any data loss in my tests, but are there some cases where doing this could result in data corruption on C?

Intuitively, this should be a safe operation. Since neither B nor C do a failover, they will remain on the same [timeline](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-TIMELINES) as A, and since the new master for C is "upstream" of the previous master, C can never be ahead of the WAL position of the new master.

**Followup question (to be answered iff the previously described operation is deemed "safe"):**
Imagine that I perform the above steps, B comes back online, I rebuild it from A and start binary streaming replication from A such that I now have the following scenario:

```
A --> B 
|
V
C
```

where A is the replication master for both B and C.

I want to make B become C's replication master again, and like before, I want to minimize C's downtime. Can I stop the Postgres service on C, ensure that the WAL playback position on B is further along than that of C (waiting for B to catch up with C if C was "ahead" of B in WAL playback), then switch the replication master host for C to point at B in the recovery.conf file and start the Postgres service?

Once again, I've done this in practice and it seems to work, but I want to be sure that there aren't any scenarios that result in data corruption on C. In this second case, assume that replication from A to B is verified to be working correctly when Postgres on C is turned off (if replication from A to B breaks while C is still replicating from A, there can be divergence between C's and B's databases, which will obviously cause problems). Is this a safe operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. B is an identical copy of A that must always be at or behind it in time, so it is safe to switch replication from B to A.

Personally, though, I'd use WAL shipping from A as my fallback. I'd leave streaming replication configured to use B. If it's unreachable, C will try the WAL archives, and it'll find the WAL archives from A and replay from them, periodically retrying B until it can connect again.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking as well. Thanks!